# App to mount iPhone as disk accessible from Terminal

Tags: iphone, terminal, backup, rsync, sftp

Is there an app which mounts my iPhone as an external drive on my Mac through wifi so that I can access its files from Terminal? It would be great if I could sync files with rsync (or maybe even unison).

The goal would be to have a complete copy of my files from my Mac, on my iPhone — which I would periodically update (for example with rsync). I have tried using acrosync for this, but it is quite slow and hasn't been updated in years.

Comment: iOS apps are sandboxed, so even those which allow remote access can only do this for their own files. Would a cloud storage solution work for you?

Comment: [Commander One](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/commander-one-file-manager/id1035236694?mt=12) supports mounting your iPhone as an external drive from your Terminal, and it's free. You plug in your iPhone, open Commander One, click your iPhone from the top menu, click View in the top menu, then click Show Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

First up, there are two routes, paid and free with a few installs

**1) Paid apps**

There are a few apps that allow you to mount your iPhone as an external drive on your Mac and access it through Terminal. Two such apps are [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) and [MacX MediaTrans](https://www.macxdvd.com/mediatrans/)*, which allow you to browse and manage the files on your iPhone or iPad (or iPod Touch).

There is [an article](https://helpdesk.macroplant.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019027213-Mount-your-iPhone-or-iPad-as-an-external-drive) on iExplorer's helpdesk site on how to do this. Apparently, iExplorer can let you mount any directory on your iPhone as an external drive and copy files of any kind. You need to right-click a directory in iExplorer and choose Mount as Disk.

Likewise [this article](https://www.macxdvd.com/mac-dvd-video-converter-how-to/mount-iphone-as-hard-disk-drive.htm) describes how it's done with MacX MediaTrans.

At the moment, I don't have the need to do what you need it for, but remember using iExplorer for that same purpose many years ago.

Note that [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer/buy) and [MacX MediaTrans](https://www.macxdvd.com/mediatrans/buy.htm) are paid apps, but you can download a free trial to see if it meets your needs before purchasing.

---

. * Labelled named "iPhone Manager" on their home page

Disclosure: I'm not affiliated with Macroplant, maker of iExplorer, or Digiarty, maker of MacX MediaTrans.

> 

**2) Free**

A bit more digging revealed that (surprise) there are others who had the same issue. You can use `ifuse`, which is a FUSE filesystem driver that uses `libimobiledevice` to connect to iOS devices.

A Superuser question from 2012 provided some options and solutions, incl. jailbraking, which I won't be recommending. Instead I'll point you to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/465394/how-can-i-mount-an-iphone-as-a-drive-on-os-x/1135668#1135668) from 2016.

If you're happy with installing packages and the Terminal (which by the looks of your question you do) and don't want to pay for yet another app, this is probably the way you want to approach this.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you, the approach number 2 worked but I had to change a few things:
- now macFuse is used instead of osxfuse
- I also did sudo port install libimobiledevice
- I installed ifuse with brew install gromgit/fuse/ifuse-mac (as suggested here https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1250)

Unfortunately the files app cannot be accesed but other third party apps can. To use unison I had to set 
perms = 0 
dontchmod=true